# How to get the second largest value in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Recently I discovered the `LARGE` and `SMALL` worksheet functions, one can use for determining the first, second, third, ... larges of smalles value in an array.

At least, that's what I thought:
When having a look at the array `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` (in one column or row), the `LARGE(...;2)` gives `7` as expected, but:
When having a look at the array `[1, 1, 5, 9, 9]`, I expect `LARGE(...;2)` to give `5` but instead I get `9`.

Now this makes sense : it seems that the function `LARGE(...;2)` takes the largest entry in the array (value `9` on the last but one place), deletes this and gives the larges entry of the reduced array (which still contains another `9`), but this is not what one might expect intuitively.

In order to get `5` from `[1, 1, 5, 9, 9]`, I would need something like:

```
=LARGE_OF_UNIQUE_VALUES_OF(...;2))
```

I didn't find this in `LARGE` documentation.

Does anybody know an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: you want a helper column that generates a unique list.  then perform your large operation on the unique list.  There is a built in command in the ribbon of excel 2013 call remove duplicates.  If you want a formula to remove duplicates a quick google sure will give you a bunch of pages that have the formula and describe how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack.

```
=LARGE(IF(YOUR_DATA=LARGE(YOUR_DATA,1),SMALL(YOUR_DATA,1)-1,YOUR_DATA),1)
```

The idea is to (a) take any value in your data that is equal to the largest element and set it to less than the smallest element, then (b) find the (new) largest element. It's OK if you want the 2nd largest, but extending to 3rd largest etc. gets progressively uglier.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

If you have the new Dynamic Array formulas:

```
=LARGE(UNIQUE(...),2)
```

If not use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,A1:A5/(MATCH(A1:A5,A1:A5)=ROW(A1:A5)),2)
```

[image]

Comment: From which Excel version are those mentioned Dynamical Array formulas available?

Comment: @Dominique see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e

Comment: Nice job of avoiding the helper column